# Using CuteCom to parse the GNSS receiver data

Tags: linux, serial-port

I used **CuteCom** tool to parse the GNSS receiver data in Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS. In the case of not receiving satellite signals, it can generate normal data. But when I went outside to receive the signal, it generated some message except NMEA sentence. Like this:
[image: CuteCom window]

I don't know what made this. Who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I have found why **CuteCom** displayed additional data. That's because the receiver will output Raw data besides NMEA sentences.